# laravel 5.5 schedule:run cron job not working in cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, shared-hosting, laravel-artisan

I'm have a laravel5.5 project up on shared hosting and trying to run cron job to execute the command "schedule:run" but it just won't execute I think I'm writing the command wrong:

```
/usr/local/bin/php home/schoolco/prototype/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

where prototype in the name of my laravel project. 
the command works in this directory using ssh. 
please if you have any observation or thought share it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/schoolco/prototype/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

And check are you calling right php executable in your terminal with:

```
$ which php
```

Maybe it is not /usr/local/bin/php , maybe /usr/bin/php

Answer (score 2):

If your Project is in Root Directory

```
cd /home/cpanel/public_html && /usr/local/bin/ea-php72 artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

If your Project in a folder within Public_Html then use below

```
 cd /home/cpanel/public_html/folder_name && /usr/local/bin/ea-php72 artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Hope it will work for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by specifying the php version in the command line:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/ea-php71 /home/nemanu/root1/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```