# laravel 8 sail, cron not running automatically

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am using laravel 8 sail, and I want to run a task repeatedly, but seems schedule task not getting called.

I have installed crontab

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab \
    && crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab \
    && touch /var/log/cron.log
```

and created crontab file

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run --no-ansi >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# Don't remove the empty line at the end of this file. It is required to run the cron job
```

And inside Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->command('inspire')->everyMinute();

   $schedule->call(function () {
      DB::table('products')->delete();
   })->everyMinute();

}
```

Normally after every minute it should run inspire command and delete products table, but nothing happen.

note: When I get inside the docker instance and run 'cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run --no-ansi >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1' it works fine but automatically not.

Comment: Just a guess: Could you try escaping the `&&` to `\&\&` in the cron job and check if it runs now?

Comment: no it didn't work, I don't think this is the problem because in the documentation they have '* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1' https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler

Comment: Ok, never mind. I actually stumbled upon the escaping issue few days ago when setting a cron job in nginx and putting a `\ ` before `&` worked.

Comment: This looks a bit relevant. Maybe a full path to php is needed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858997/laravel-5-5-schedulerun-cron-job-not-working-in-cpanel

Comment: Why `DB::table('products')->delete();` every minute?

Comment: thank you for your help, I will try writing full path for php, why deleting ? because I want to make sure the scheduling is working first before writing my logic.

Comment: @SoufianeOdf did you make it work?

Comment: @Leo if you are using the latest laravel version and you want to run it localy you can use this instead https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler-locally